# Different search views for same model

Tags: odoo

I have 2 actions (sort of "screens") for 2 subtypes of account.invoices, they are:

1. customer invoices
2. supplier invoices

A different search view is loaded in each of them, I did that specifying the search view when you click in the menu.

Then I do the search, and everything is ok, but then when I click the "clean" button, the search view changes to the most priority view of account.invoice model. 
I think I'm doing wrong and overpassing it with forcing view-rendering from the menu link, but when I click clean button, or whatever up-right button (to choose search-view,form-view...) openerp renders the most priority view of account.invoice

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you add screenshots of what you explained, because I do not see where is the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Does it possible to paste your code over hear  ??